# How to set a window's index to last (furthest back) in applescript

Tags: macos, indexing, applescript

I've seen a lot of posts for how to send a window to the front in applescript, but I want to be able to send it to the back. How do I write an applescript that will do this?

Comment: In what Application specifically? (a `Finder Window` has its own class)

Comment: It's not a finder window - it's actually an application I made in openFrameworks, so it has a specific name, and there won't be any additional instances of this window, only other windows (it will run in conjunction with max MSP). Basically, it will be used to power a portion of a performance that is being projected onto a screen, and it is launched via applescript, so when it launches, I don't want it to be visible over anything that's already being projected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you don't actually need to move any windows. Maybe you can just hide your application so your window isn't showing. Since you don't want your window on the top then it's probably OK to just hide your application. It continues running and does its thing but its window doesn't cover any other windows.

Just change "Safari" to the name of your application.

```
set myAppName to "Safari"
tell application myAppName to activate
tell application "System Events"
    -- wait until your application comes forward and then hide it
    repeat
        set p to first process whose frontmost is true
        if name of p is myAppName then
            set visible of p to false -- hide your application
            exit repeat
        end if
        delay 0.2
    end repeat
end tell
```

***EDIT***: if hiding your app doesn't work then you could just keystroke command-tab which is the application switcher command. Basically your app will come to the front and then the keystroke will make the previously frontmost application come to the front. So your window won't go all the way back but it won't be in the front. Maybe that will work.

```
set myAppName to "Safari"
tell application myAppName to activate
tell application "System Events"
    -- wait until your application comes forward
    repeat
        set p to first process whose frontmost is true
        if name of p is myAppName then exit repeat
        delay 0.2
    end repeat

    -- use the application switcher to bring the previously frontmost application forward
    keystroke tab using command down
end tell
```

Comment: I've tried this - the window captures the webcam, and if the window is minimized, the webcam stops being broadcast (freezes on the last frame visible before window was minimized) and continues updating when the window is restored.

Comment: OK. It was just a thought. If I think of something else I'll let you know. Good luck.

Comment: Well, I do have another idea. I added an EDIT section to my post.

Comment: Yeah - that will work great actually! Don't know why I didn't think of that. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Something like `set index to 999` doesn't seem to work, but `set index to (count windows)` does:

```
tell application "TextEdit"
    set index of window 1 to (count windows)
end tell
```

You might also raise all other windows:

```
tell application "System Events" to tell process "TextEdit"
    repeat with w in windows 2 thru -1
        perform action "AXRaise" of w
    end repeat
end tell
```

Answer (score 0):

This will move the front finder window to the back...

```
tell application "Finder" to set index of front Finder window to (count Finder windows)
```

Comment: Thanks - see additional clarification above. I think your answer would work if I could pass it the name of my application, and set the index to (count All windows) - is there something like that?

Comment: I think it depends if your application has window or document classes. Replace "Finder" with your app name and replace Finder window with either window or document. You may also need to replace front with window 1 or document 1.

Answer (score 0):

I have not used "openFrameWorks" so I am not sure of how it works…

But rather than reinvent the wheel with Applescript.

Can you not set the window level in "openFrameWorks"

In xcode/Objective - c  I would use the NSWindow Window Levels [constants](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/applicationkit/classes/NSWindow_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000013-SW75).

To set a normal window:

```
[awindow setLevel: NSNormalWindowLevel];
```

But set a window below other normal windows:

```
[awindow setLevel: NSNormalWindowLevel - 1000];
```

This will insure the window is always below any normal applications windows. Even when I click on it or drag it. It stays behind other windows.